# Meaning of "Rubber stamp"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *rubber stamp* in "rubber stamp National Assembly"? Does this imply that the assembly has no real power? Where did this originate?

Comment: This is general reference.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions are expected to show some research, and this can be answered easily via Google, hence the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Rubber stamp (politics):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_stamp_%28politics%29)
>
> A rubber stamp, as a political metaphor, refers to a person or
>   institution with considerable *[de jure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure) (legal) power* but little *[de facto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) (factual) 
>   power*; one that rarely disagrees with more powerful
>   organs.

Comment: accepted but no up vote?!

Answer (score 4):

It does. The OED’s definition of the noun *rubber stamp* when used this way is ‘a person or institution whose power is formal but not real; a person who or body which endorses uncritically’. The point of the expression is to show that individuals or organizations approve what is put to them without question, just as an official might use a rubber stamp to automatically print something like *APPROVED* on a document without reading it. The first recorded use in this sense is dated 1910.